# How draw dynamic empty rectangle over a bitmap?

Tags: graphics, dynamic

I am trying to make a cookie cutter that will extract a small square from a much larger bitmap with a click of the mouse. The `LocatorPane` appears to be a useful way to move the cookie cutter around, but I'm not having much luck in drawing the small dynamic rectangle over the bitmap. I would like to change the appearance of the locator icon to a small rectangle, or just make the locator icon disappear. The `LocatorPane` option `Appearance -> Graphics[Rectangle[]]` didn't work. Beyond that there is the question of how to capture a point value with a mouse click. This is my first use of `Dynamic`. I suspect I am going about this all the wrong way and perhaps I should be doing something with mouse functions and cursor images. If so, I would appreciate it if someone would point me towards a pertinent page or two. I have not been able to find one.

This script draws the locator on a bitmap labeled "background":

```
Clear[background]          
background = Image[Graphics[{LightGray, Rectangle[]}]];
DynamicModule[     {pt = {180, 180}},      LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt], background]     ]
```

But when I add code for the dynamic rectangle, I find that it draws outside the background bitmap.

```
 DynamicModule[ {pt = {180, 180}},  
  {LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt], background], 
   Graphics[ 
     {EdgeForm[{Thick, Red}], 
      FaceForm[], Rectangle[Dynamic[pt]]} 
   ]}  
 ]
```

Comment: Related: Szabolcs applied the crop rectangle to zoom into graphics objects [here](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2008/Jan/msg00009.html).

Comment: Also see image cropper [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4753250#4753250).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Combine the background and the Graphics with `Show`, so that you can supply both of them as the second argument to `LocatorPane`:

```
background = Image[Graphics[{LightGray, Rectangle[]}]];
DynamicModule[{pt1 = {180, 180}, pt2 = {20, 20}},
 LocatorPane[Dynamic[{pt1, pt2}],
  Show[
   background,
   Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Thick, Red}],
     FaceForm[], Rectangle[Dynamic[pt1], Dynamic[pt2]]}]]
  , Appearance -> Graphics[Rectangle[], ImageSize -> {10, 10}]]]
```

[image]

**Update** After further clarification of the question:

```
background = Image[Graphics[{LightGray, Rectangle[]}]];
DynamicModule[{pt1 = {180, 170}, pt2 = {190, 180}}, 
 LocatorPane[Dynamic[{pt1(*,pt2*)}], 
  Show[background, 
   Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Thick, Red}], FaceForm[], 
     Dynamic[Rectangle[pt1 + {5, 5}, pt1 - {5, 5}]]}]], Appearance -> None]]
```